# What is relevant Field for SelectedValue (Combobox) in ComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress

What is the relevant field of `Combobox.SelectedValue` in `ComboboxEdit`.

When I choose something from:

```
in Devexpress ComboboxEdit .. 
combo.EditValue ="1​"
combo.SelectedItem="1​"
combo.SelectedText​="1"
```

These all get the same value. In Normal Winform Combobox.

```
cmb.SelectedItem="1"
cmb.SelectedText=""
cmb.SelectedValue=null​
```

How can I achieve this in Devexpress ComboxEdit?

For example, I am having:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
             
dic.Add("Test","5");
dic.Add("Test","6");
dic.Add("Test","7");

foreach(DictionaryEntry dic in dic)
{
 Combobox.Items.add(dic);
 Comboboxedit.Properties.Items.Add(dic);
}
```

When I am setting the value for normal:

```
Combobox WinForm
Combobox.SelectedValue = dic["Test"];
```

How can I do the same thing for Devexpress `ComboboxEdit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need DevEx control that behaves like winforms standard combobox you should use [LookupEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) control.

From [ComboBoxEdit documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxEdittopic):

*ComboBoxEdit combines the functionality of a single-line text editor with the dropdown window.

ComboBoxEdit items can be of any type. In the dropdown window and edit box, **items are represented by their display texts (strings returned by the item's ToString method)**. 
**When you select an item from the dropdown, a corresponding object from the item collection is automatically assigned to the SelectedItem property.** 
This property value matches the edit value available via the EditValue property.*

So, in ComboBoxEdit you can't have display and value member, it just displays string representations of items.

**EDIT**(bind dictionary to LookupEdit):

```cs
LookUpEdit lookupEdit = new LookUpEdit();
Dictionary<string,string>  dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dic["1"] = "jedan";
dic["2"] = "dva";
lookupEdit.Properties.ValueMember = "Key";
lookupEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = "Value";
lookupEdit.Properties.DataSource = dic.ToList();

// if you want to hide Key column
LookUpColumnInfo keyColumnInfo = new LookUpColumnInfo("Key");
keyColumnInfo.Visible = false;
lookupEdit.Properties.Columns.Add(keyColumnInfo);
lookupEdit.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("Value"));

// set selected item
lookupEdit.EditValue = "2";
```

Comment: Lookupedit is also not having the property of SelectedValue .. it do the same thing

Comment: You should explain what exactly are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: @ Filip Just bind List as DataSource. Then get SelectedValue and Cast it to your Type.